# nopcommerce 3.40 themes changing

Tags: visual-studio, themes, nopcommerce

I am getting ready to start customizing nopCommerce the way I want it to look.  My initial thought was that i would just hack away at the master Layout and push my own Css on top of it all.

then I thought. Wait. Their are themes, even better, their are free themes.  So I think that I should download a theme and start hacking away at that project before installing it from the NopCommerce admin side.

I looked inside this theme. for example --> http://www.nopcommerce.com/p/1381/noproot-bootstrap-theme-free.aspx

Yea, there is a lot going on in here and a lot of files.  Does anyone have some brief knowledge to give me on the inner workings of these pre-built themes.  Maybe some insight as to what the configure file does to distribute the files, css, views and or change routes in the original configuration.

Or can someone tell me what pages(views),css I can touch without blowing anything up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you edit the existing theme of the nopcommerce then you will end-up having a single theme. This should not be done in this way.
There are good practices to create/install nopcommerce theme. Just consider how you can have multiple themes active at the same time so that you can switch between them.

The idea is to have separate folders for each of the themes and the view files.

Here you can find information regarding the config file: http://docs.nopcommerce.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1442509
Here you can find everything about the nopCommerce theme and the structures: http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/nc/Designer's+Guide

Hope this helps.